# Re-export namespace from external module to global in declaration file

Tags: typescript, declaration, typescript-declarations

I'm running into some problem exporting, like it's said on title, a namespace from an external module to the global namespace in a declaration file. Here I'll post the piece of code to better explain my problem.

***//SomeClass.d.ts** - I have to declare classes like this due to a not pertinent reason*

```
interface SomeClassConstructor {
    new(): SomeClass;
    prototype: SomeClass;
    /* static method and variables of SomeClass*/
}
interface SomeClass {
    /* method and variables of SomeClass */
}
declare const SomeClass: SomeClassConstructor;
export = SomeClass;
```

***//externalModule.d.ts***

```
import SomeClass_ = require("./SomeClass");
interface Module {
    /* declarations */
    SomeClass: typeof SomeClass_;
}
declare namespace Module {
    /* other declarations */
    export type SomeClass = SomeClass_;
}
export = Module;
```

***//module.d.ts***

```
import module = require("./externalModule");
declare global {
    interface Window {
        Module: module;
    }
    // What insert here to access Module as a namespace
}
// var someObject: /* like this here: --> */ Module.SomeClass = new window.Module.SomeClass();
//this below of course works, but I need to acces Module globally
var someOtherObject: module.SomeClass = new module.SomeClass();
```

**Edit:** Maybe this could help someone to answer this question.

I discovered that doing this:

**__//script.ts__**

```
/// <reference path="module.d.ts"/>
const Module = window.Module;
var SomeClass = new window.Module.SomeClass();
```

by type inference I got **SomeClass** as type: **Module.SomeClass**, and I can access the type doing:

```
var someObject: typeof SomeClass;
```

However I have to replace `var SomeClass = new window.Module.SomeClass()` with `var SomeClass;` (that gives a type of **any**) in order to avoid unwanted **Module.SomeClass** initializations.
It is a bad workaround that I would preferably avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing the following doesn't work, because `const`s and namespaces are distinct:

```
// module.d.ts
declare global {
    interface Window {
        Module: module;
    }
    const Module: typeof module;
    type Module = typeof module;
}
```

The following should work however:

```
//module.d.ts
import module = require("./externalModule");
export = module
export as namespace Module
declare global {
    interface Window {
        Module: typeof module;
    }
}
```

Note that if you can modify externalModule.d.ts, you can just add the `export as namespace Module` declaration there.

Comment: Just test it, but it gives me
error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Module'.
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Module'.

However I could modify externalModule.d.ts but I have to keep it as a local module..

Comment: @GiulianoCollacchioni copy and paste snafu, sorry. Try now.